# POST JSON data to power bi api 404 ERROR

Tags: json, api, post, python-requests, powerbi

I'm pushing a csv, converted to a JSON file, to my power bi api. Each individual column is shown correctly on power bi, however, when confronting the code with adding rows to the column, I receive a 404 error:

```
Succes:  200
Succes:  200
response status dataset:  201 
dataset responses:  200

response status rows:  404 {"error":{"code":"ItemNotFound","message":"Column '<pi>event_name</pi>' was not found in specified table, dataset 'sobe_wowvirtualserver|*somenumberhere*'"}}
```

These are the columns that were uploaded with success:

```
columns_body_raw = {"name": "test", "tables":
    [
        {"name": "test", "columns": 
            [
                { "name": "id", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "status", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "location", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "reportLocation", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "preferences", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "activity_description", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "activity_qualification", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "activity_businessActivity", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "activity_abbreviation", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "planned_start_date", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "planned_start_time", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "planned_end_date", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "planned_end_time", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "planned_duration", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "projected_cost", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "clock_in_date", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "clock_in_time", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "clock_out_date", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "clock_out_time", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "clocked_duration", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "break_duration", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "price", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "order_no", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "event_id", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "department", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "department_cost_center", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "worker_first_name", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "worker_preposition", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "worker_last_name", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "worker_full_name", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "personnel_number", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "partner", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "employee_type", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "employee_default_cost_center", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "authorized_partner", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "incident", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "tags", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "sketch_start_date", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "sketch_start", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "sketch_end_date", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "sketch_end", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "delta_time", "dataType": "string"},
                { "name": "delta_plan", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "delta_clock", "dataType": "Int64"},
                { "name": "event_name", "dataType": "string"} #this is one of the columns that gives an error

            ]
        }
dataset_body = json.dumps(columns_body_raw)
```

And this these are some of the rows where my error occurs:

```
dataset_body_raw = { "rows": [{
            "sketch_end": "0",
            "order_no": "2017",
            "activity_qualification": "TEST",
            "clock_out_date": "0",
            "activity_businessActivity": "BUSINESS NAME TEST",
            "clock_in_time": "0",
            "partner": "COMPANY",
            "event_name": "EVENT"
            }]}
    dataset_body = json.dumps(dataset_body_raw)
```

The 404 error states that there is no event_name column, though it is listed in the columns_body_raw and I can see it in my power bi environment.

This is a screenshot of power bi:
[image: event_name column]

Comment: Seems to me that the problem isn't that the column is missing from your request, but rather from the schema. A 404 signifies that a resource isn't found on the server, not missing from the client's request.

So seems to me you're trying to insert something in a column called event_name, but that column doesn't exist in whatever you're trying to post it to.

You say you see it in the environment, can you post a screenshot of that too? Maybe you're in the wrong nesting level or something.

Comment: I've added a screenshot, previous posts to power bi api were successful with different datasets. So I can't pinpoint the error here.

Comment: Is `event_name` a column you added later on, *after* the data set was created? Did you try recreating the data set? Did you try adding a new column with another name?

Comment: The issue was resolved. Maybe mark it as resolved @RA / post the answer or something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong response dataset id, therefore the dataset linked to an older version of a dataset in power bi, which did not include that specific column. Concluding: the code above is the correct way to post rows in a column with the power bi API.